# GL_INVALID_OPERATION setting image2D in computeShader

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am using OpenGL ES 3.2 and the NVIDIA driver 361.00 on a Pixel C tablet with Tegra X1 GPU. I would like to use a compute shader to write data to a colour map and then later I will use some graphics shaders to display the image.

I already have this concept working using desktop GL and now I want to port to mobile. I am implementing the GL in Java rather than in native code. I extend `GLSurfaceView` and the `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` and then during the `OnSurfaceCreated` callback I initialise the shader programs and textures etc.

The compute shader compiles just fine without any errors:

```
#version 310 es
layout(binding = 0, rgba32f) uniform highp image2D colourMap;
layout(local_size_x = 128, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

void main()
{
    imageStore(colourMap, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
}
```

And I initialise a texture

```
// Generate a 2D texture
GLES31.glGenTextures(1, colourMap, 0);
GLES31.glBindTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, colourMap[0]);

// Set interpolation to nearest
GLES31.glTexParameteri(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES31.GL_LINEAR);
GLES31.glTexParameteri(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES31.GL_LINEAR);

// Create some dummy texture to begin with so we can see if it changes
float texData[] = new float[texWidth * texHeight * 4];
for (int j = 0; j < texHeight; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < texWidth; i++)
    {
        // Set a few pixels in here...
    }
}
Buffer texDataBuffer = FloatBuffer.wrap(texData);
GLES31.glTexImage2D(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES31.GL_RGBA32F, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GLES31.GL_RGBA, GLES31.GL_FLOAT, texDataBuffer);
```

After this I set the image unit in the shader here: **EDIT: I don't do this now but just assume it will be assigned automatically when the shader program is created as per solidpixel's answer.**

```
GLES31.glUseProgram(idComputeShaderProgram);
int loc = GLES31.glGetUniformLocation(idComputeShaderProgram, "colourMap");
if (loc == -1) Log.e("Error", "Cannot locate variable");
GLES31.glUniform1i(loc, 0);
```

After every call to GL I check for errors using `GLES31.glGetError()` -- left out here for clarity.

**EDIT: When I dispatch compute I bind the image texture but first query the unit assignment:**

```
GLES31.glUseProgram(idComputeShaderProgram);
int[] unit = new int[1];
GLES31.glGetUniformiv(idComputeShaderProgram, GLES31.glGetUniformLocation(idComputeShaderProgram, "colourMap"), unit, 0);
GLES31.glBindImageTexture(unit[0], velocityMap[0], 0, false, 0, GLES31.GL_WRITE_ONLY, GLES31.GL_RGBA32F);
```

This final line is the one which errors now. The error code translates to `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. The shader compiles correctly and the program object is valid and active. The location of the variable is also valid. I have even used `glGetActiveUniform()` to get the type of the variable and it returns a type of 36941 which translates to `GL_IMAGE_2D` which I believe is an integer.

I still think I'm misunderstanding something here but not sure what.

Comment: Have the same problem on Samsung S7 Edge with Mali-T800 GPU, GLES 3.2 and Android 7.0.

Comment: I am getting the same gl error now at the same line. Have you solved it?

Comment: @Sung yes, I solved it using the answer below and the documentation I quoted in the comments to the answer relating to allocating textures.

Comment: Yeap, it is solved by glTexStorage2D() + glTexSubImage2D() instead of glTexImage2D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign your own unit identities for images. See OpenGL ES 3.2 specification section 7.6.

> An INVALID_OPERATION error is generated if any of the following
>   conditions occur:
>
> - an image uniform is loaded with any of the Uniform* commands.

You need to query the automatic unit assignment using `glGetUniformiv(prog, loc, &unit)` to get the unit name.

Comment: thank you for your answer. So when in the uniform assigned, when the compute shader program is created? How do I ensure that the image2D variable in the shader will access the texture I created -- do I just make sure I bind the texture to the correct target? A corrected code snippet might help?

Comment: OK so I just deleted trying to assign a unit id to the `image2D` variable in the shader and instead, before calling `glBindImageTexture`, used your recommendation to get the unit number then used that unit number in the `glBindImageTexture` call. It still gives me a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error.

Comment: I've made some edits to the question to reflect my changes.

Comment: In terms of "self-help", does your device support the KHR_debug extensions? Android exposes this via Java bindings, and it normally gives much better error messages.

Comment: In terms of reading the specification "GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if texture is not the name of an immutable texture object".

Comment: yes I just found that myself and was about to post it here. I'll keep digging. I assume if it must be immutable, I can't write to the texture from the shader with `imageStore`?

Comment: This page: (https://arm-software.github.io/opengl-es-sdk-for-android/compute_intro.html) has a special note about halfway down that covers both the "don't use Uniform*" and "use immutable storage" issues we are covering here. They say that you must allocate textures using `glTexStorage2D()` rather than `glTexImage2D()`.